# Fill the null values in R dataframe with default but distinct values

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, na

I have a R dataframe where one of the column has no values. I want to fill this values with distinct value.

```
id  var1   var2   var3
A   25      26     abc
B   28      35     abk
C   55      46      
D   64      az     lft
J   cd      yz      
M   dg      ck     ja
......................
.........
```

I want to fill those null values with a default but distinct values.

Expected output:

```
   id  var1   var2   var3
A   25      26     abc
B   28      35     abk
C   55      46     NA1 
D   64      az     lft
J   cd      yz     NA2
M   dg      ck     ja
so now the other null value will be filled with NA3
```

Solution using R and pandas both would be nice to compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [`R`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info)

```
df$var3 = as.character(df$var3)
df$var3 = replace(df$var3, df$var3 == "", paste0(NA, sequence(sum(df$var3 == ""))))
df
#  d var1 var2 var3
#1 A   25   26  abc
#2 B   28   35  abk
#3 C   55   46  NA1
#4 D   64   az  lft
#5 J   cd   yz  NA2
#6 M   dg   ck   ja
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(d = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "J", "M"), var1 = c("25", 
"28", "55", "64", "cd", "dg"), var2 = c("26", "35", "46", "az", 
"yz", "ck"), var3 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
"abc", "abk", "ja", "lft"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("d", 
"var1", "var2", "var3"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It did add the "NA" but didn't add the sequence number after NA.

Comment: `Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = c("NA1", "NA2", "NA3", "NA4",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`

Comment: Also, using `make.unique`, something like `make.unique(rep("val", sum(df$var3 == "")))` should do it and `df$var3 == ""` could be written `!nzchar(df$var3)`. Unsure of speed implications.

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table`, this is accomplished by

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[var3 == "", var3 := rowid(var3, prefix = "NA")][]
```

> ```
>    id var1 var2 var3
> 1:  A   25   26  abc
> 2:  B   28   35  abk
> 3:  C   55   46  NA1
> 4:  D   64   az  lft
> 5:  J   cd   yz  NA2
> 6:  M   dg   ck   ja
> ```

Note that this works with character or factor columns without conversion. The assignment operator `:=` replaces only updated elements of `DF$var3` *in place*, i.e., without copying the whole data object in order to save time and memory.

This can be verified by executing `address(DF$var3)` before and after the update statement. The [base R solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47127209/3817004) copies the whole data.frame `df` twice (check with `address(df)`).

#### Data

```
DF <- read.table(fill = TRUE, header = TRUE, 
text = "id  var1   var2   var3
A   25      26     abc
B   28      35     abk
C   55      46      
D   64      az     lft
J   cd      yz      
M   dg      ck     ja")

str(DF)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  4 variables:
>  $ id  : Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
>  $ var1: Factor w/ 6 levels "25","28","55",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
>  $ var2: Factor w/ 6 levels "26","35","46",..: 1 2 3 4 6 5
>  $ var3: Factor w/ 5 levels "","abc","abk",..: 2 3 1 5 1 4
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `make.unique` to fill in unique values. For example,

```
dat$var3 <- as.character(dat$var3)
dat$var3[!nzchar(dat$var3)] <- make.unique(rep("val", sum(!nzchar(dat$var3))))
```

returns

```
dat
  d var1 var2  var3
1 A   25   26   abc
2 B   28   35   abk
3 C   55   46   val
4 D   64   az   lft
5 J   cd   yz val.1
6 M   dg   ck    ja
```

You can adjust the default separator using the sep argument and can also put whatever stub to use as the base. I used "val" here. `nzchar` is another method to check for non-empty strings like `!= ""`. I used `!` initially to reverse the output and indicate empty strings.